# Wordpress Menu CSS code only works when hovering over, how can i fix

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, padding

I'm building a website https://gamingplus.gg/ , I want the "Trending" tab to be next to News, I have the CSS code right but it only works when your hover over the tab. How do I have this work automatically without hovering over

Simple CSS just only working when I hover.

```
.trending-inline.dropper.drop-it.mm-art.mm-wrap.active-1 {
    margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

Should work when the page is loaded without hovering.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then put the styles applied when is hover to the style

```
.trending-inline.dropper.drop-it.mm-art.mm-wrap {
    margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

Is not the most elegant solution, but will fit your needs.